# Error when I run ‘git push heroku master’

Tags: python, tensorflow, heroku

The error is:

```
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
...
...
...
remote:          error: libhdf5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
remote:          ERROR: Failed building wheel for h5py
```

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn run:app
```

Requirements.txt

```
appnope==0.1.2
astunparse==1.6.3
backcall==0.2.0
cachetools==5.0.0
certifi==2021.10.8
charset-normalizer==2.0.10
click==8.0.4
cycler==0.11.0
debugpy==1.5.1
decorator==5.1.1
entrypoints==0.3
Flask==2.0.3
flatbuffers==1.12
fonttools==4.29.1
gast==0.3.3
gunicorn==20.1.0
google-auth==2.5.0
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.6
google-pasta==0.2.0
grpcio==1.32.0
h5py==2.10.0
idna==3.3
importlib-metadata==4.10.1
ipykernel==6.6.1
ipython==7.31.0
itsdangerous==2.1.0
jedi==0.18.1
Jinja2==3.0.3
jupyter-client==7.1.0
jupyter-core==4.9.1
keras==2.7.0
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.2
kiwisolver==1.3.2
libclang==12.0.0
Markdown==3.3.6
MarkupSafe==2.1.0
matplotlib==3.5.1
matplotlib-inline==0.1.3
nest-asyncio==1.5.4
numpy==1.19.5
oauthlib==3.1.1
opencv-python==4.5.5.62
opt-einsum==3.3.0
packaging==21.3
parso==0.8.3
pexpect==4.8.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow==9.0.1
prompt-toolkit==3.0.24
protobuf==3.19.3
ptyprocess==0.7.0
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
Pygments==2.11.2
pyparsing==3.0.7
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pyzmq==22.3.0
requests==2.27.1
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
rsa==4.8
six==1.15.0
tensorboard==2.8.0
tensorboard-data-server==0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.8.1
./machine_learning/tensorflow-2.4.1-py3-none-any.whl
tensorflow-estimator==2.4.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem==0.23.1
termcolor==1.1.0
tornado==6.1
traitlets==5.1.1
typing-extensions==3.7.4.3
urllib3==1.26.8
wcwidth==0.2.5
Werkzeug==2.0.2
wrapt==1.12.1
zipp==3.7.0
```

##### Notes

- h5py is installed
- working in a virtualenv
- `pip install -r requirements.txt` works just fine
- My website uses Flask backend
- I have Python buildpack enabled in Heroku

##### What might be causing the problem

- I'm installing Tensorflow 2.4.1 with a local .whl file in my requirements.txt file
- I'm on a Mac with the M1 chip which causes some problems with Tensorflow and its dependencies

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install -y pkg-config libhdf5-100 libhdf5-dev`?

Comment: @RobG, you can't install things on Heroku via `sudo apt-get install` due to its ephemeral filesystem. To add an OS-level package, OP would have to use [the apt buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt).

Comment: @RobG I am on a Mac, so I don't think I can use `apt-get`

Comment: @Chris I added apt buildpack and creted an Aptfile with `pkg-config
libhdf5-dev
python3-h5py
libhdf5-103`. But i'm still getting the same error.